# How to replace string in column names of pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, regex-replace

I have a pyspark data frame that every column appends the table name ie: Table.col1,  Table.col2...

I would like to replace 'Table.' with '' (nothing) in every column in my dataframe.

How do I do this?  Everything I have found deals with doing this to the values in the columns and not the column names themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`toDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF.html) with [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) :

> `DataFrame.toDF(*cols)`
> Returns a new DataFrame that with **new specified column names**

```
out = df.toDF(*[c.replace("Table.", "") for c in df.columns])
```

Output :

```
out.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| foo|   1|
| bar|   2|
+----+----+
```

*Input used :*

```
+----------+----------+
|Table.col1|Table.col2|
+----------+----------+
|       foo|         1|
|       bar|         2|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it in **PySpark**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
new_columns = [col(column_name).alias(column_name.replace('Table.', '')) for column_name in df.columns]
df_new = df.select(new_columns)
```

Also, if anyone want to do the same in **Pandas**:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Table.', '')
```